# How to find the state-variable equations from the signal flow graph of the system?

Tags: control-system

How to find the state-variable equations, i.e, the state equation & the output equation for the system described by the signal flow graph below?

[image: Signal flow graph of the system]

Answer (score 3):

Though the question was asked three years ago but i think the solution might be a bit of help for anyone trying to solve state space equations problems.
The most important concept to keep in mind in such types of problems is that the output of the integrator is taken to be the state variable.
The solution goes as follows:
[image]

[image]

As one can see, to start with the outputs of the integrator was taken to be the state variable and just to keep the state equations in their generalized form, we made slight change in the state variable, i.e. a multiplication factor of 1/s else the equation would have a component involving **sU** which would certainly not fall in line with the generalized state space equations.

Comment: "the output of the integrator is taken to be the state variable" this is only true when the output of the integrator does not have any other arrow pointing at it i.e only the integrator is pointing at the said point. Caution must be exercised if this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Between each point you have to define a state-variable and it will give you this equations:

$$
\begin{align}
& X_1 = U \\
& X_2 = -X_1 \\
& X_1(point)=X_2 \\
& X_2 = -X_1 \\
& X_2(point) = X_3 \\
& X_3 = -X_2 \\
& X_3(point) = -X_3 \\
& Y = X_3 \\
\end{align}
$$

$$
X(point) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}*X \\
Y= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}X 
$$
For example you have \$ X_3 (t) = C_0 \cdot ^{(-t)} \$ (if you solve this equation).

Comment: I've updated the formulas with MathJax, feel free to give it a look and modify it to your liking. The Meta has a lot of help.

Comment: Why are some `x` points?, do you have a reference to a similar example?, or links to resources for obtaining the transition function given a SFG?